# What does the extension .c stands for in C

Tags: c

I wasnt abe to find the meaning of the extension `.c` of the source files in C language.
If the extension `.h` stands for **header**, then what `.c` stands for?

Comment: I guess `c` stands for _C programming language_ ;-)

Comment: Perhaps what might be confusing for some people is that `.c` is lowercase whereas `C` is uppercase...

Comment: Is this.... Are you... Do you even... What am I reading?

Comment: I am tempted to upvote that question. Because I like it ;). .c could, however, mean ***c**ompiler input* and .C *input for the bigger compiler*

Comment: The question contains the answer.

Comment: wrong way to get rep through question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C in .c stands for **C**. C is the name of the C programming language.

Comment: didn't see that one coming... :))

Comment: Indeed bolov. We can't verify that you didn't see that one coming if you don't cite any sources.

Comment: @VeronikaPrüssels umm... common sense...

Comment: @VeronikaPrüssels Then `.cpp` comes from code plus plus...

Answer (score 2):

"The C in .c stands for C. C is the name of the C programming language", as Zoidberg said in his answer.

However, it should be noted that this is a convention, i.e. to name C source files with a .c extension. It could have been anything, but choosing ".c" makes common sense and everyone uses it. Even compilers and IDEs default to looking for .c files for C source files. As it is a "common sense" convention, it does not need to be documented. The container (the filename) is not described in the standard.

It would have been a common sense convention too to name them `.KnR` (why not).